# Can zip files be sparse/non-contiguous?

Tags: c++, c, compression, zip, archive

The zip file format ends with a central directory section that then points to the individual zip entries within the file. This appears to allow zip entries to occur anywhere within the zip file itself. Indeed, self-extracting zip files are a good example: they start with an executable and all the zip entries occur after the executable bytes.

The question is: **does the zip file format really allow sparse or non-contiguous zip entries?** e.g. if there are empty or otherwise unaccounted bytes between zip entries? Both the definitive PK note and wikipedia article seem to allow this. Will all/most typical zip utilities work with such sparse zip files?

The use case is this: I want to be able to delete or replace zip entries in a zip file. To do this, the typical minizip etc. libraries want you to copy out the entire zip file while not copying out the deleted or replaced zip entry, which seems wasteful and slow.

Wouldn't it be better to over-allocate, say 1.5x the storage for an entry, then when deleting or replacing an entry you could figure out where the unallocated bytes were and use those directly? Using 1.5x the storage means that if the zip entry grew linearly, the reallocations should also happen amortized linearly. It would be similar to file system block allocation though probably not as sophisticated.

This also helps with a lot of the zip-based file formats out there. Instead of having to have some temp directory somewhere (or even in memory) with the temporarily unzipped files for editing/changing and then having to rezip the lot back into the file format, this would lessen the need for rezipping and rewriting portions of the zip file.

**Are there any C/C++ libraries out there that do this?**

Comment: Doesn't overallocating storage kind of defeat the purpose of compression?

Comment: zip file is not best media for dynamic storage management. it is archive. zip your data together and done.

Comment: Some data e.g. English text or XML, could be compressed up to 10x. Over-allocating only 0.5x extra space would still be worth it, if it allowed the whole zip file not to be rewritten. This over-allocation could be determined at an API level, so that e.g. entries known to be unlikely to increase in size can be allocated just enough space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Reading the central directory is optional.  zip decoders can, and some do, simply read the zip file sequentially from the beginning, expecting to see the local headers and entry data contiguously. They can complete the job of decoding, never having even looked at the central directory.

In order to do what you want, you would need to put in dummy zip entries between the useful entries in order to hold that space.  At least if you want to be compatible with the rest of the zip world.

Comment: What would running such a zip decoder on a non-contiguous zip file do (assuming no dummy zip entries)? If the decoder is sequentially scanning the zip file for the zip entry magic number, then decoding the entry to determine how long the data really is, it would seem the non-contiguous zip would still be compatible. About the only caveat would be that I'd have to zero out the empty space to prevent stray magic numbers from confusing the decoder.

Comment: The decoder isn't searching for a magic number.  It is expecting that the next thing it will see is a magic number that indicates whether it's a local header, central directory header, or end header.  If it sees zeros, it will stop right there with an invalid format error.

Comment: In the end I wrote my own Objective-C library to do this rezipping. It doesn't treat the zip entries as sparse entries, but it does skip writing out zip entries that haven't changed. So if you're constantly changing the last few entries, you won't have to pay for rewriting all the entries from the beginning. https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap

Comment: Strange answer that says no, but gives a way to do it anyway. If I understand correctly, if you put a zip's local header saying that the upcoming data is in a unknown compression format, then fill the area with 0 up to size written in the header, it will work ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "work".  That will cause errors when unzipping.

Comment: An anonymous user (anonymous? really?) tried to add this to the answer: "Actually, this doesn't seem to be strictly correct, according to parts 4.3.1 and 4.3.2 of the PK AppNote.", in response to my statement "Use of the central directory is optional." I did not mean that _having_ a central directory is optional. I meant that _using_ the central directory when reading the zip file is optional. I will try to clarify the statement.